# JPA : order list of entities in function of associations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, openjpa

I have a list of JPA entities , and I want to know automatically the order used to generate Database schema , for example :

- if Entity A has an association with Entity B , so Table B must be created  before Table A ,  ( I need to know this order for synchronization purposes)

Comment: It isn't clear why you would need the order.  Database schemas are created up front, once and only once and the order not matter.  It can create tables in any random order and update constraints later, or have it all done upfront.  If you want a specific order for DDL, I'd suggest you create your own DDL scripts and have your provider execute them if/when needed.  https://dzone.com/articles/generating-database-schemas

Comment: I need to know the order for synchronization issue : I send many entities from a server to another to update the their DBs , so during persisting entities i need to know the order of persiste to avoid any integrity isssues .

Comment: That isn't table creation or schema generation, that is insertion/update/delete ordering.  Those other servers should theoretically be using the same application, and so use the same ordering though, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 0):

When you start your application , hibernate has a behavior  to check the existing schemas (weather or not they persist or not). If the schemas are missing you should see hibernate Logging meta data messages such as (Table Found *table name *) for each and every table. I think that is what you are looking for . It generates all metadata info every time it scans your entity like table found , table created, table not found.